# Output changes in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory

So I've been working on this project where it's main purpose is to record sales for a company...
I am also fairly new to all sorts of programming.
My problem here is that there's a problem with the output where some of the sales should be recorded but output zero instead.
I've been doing lots of research about pointers and memory allocation and I think I kind of understand most of the concepts but there's lots left to learn...
so here's a sample of the output

```
1. Enter sales data.
2. Add a record for a new branch.
3. Delete record of an existing branch.
4. Calculate total sales.
5. Calculate percentage share of each branch.
6. Determine the month of peak sales.
7. Display sales of a specific month.
8. Display sales of a specific branch.
0. Done
1
Ender number of branches: 1

Sales for branch 1: 
Sales for month 1: 1
Sales for month 2: 1
Sales for month 3: 1
Sales for month 4: 1
Sales for month 5: 1
Sales for month 6: 1
Sales for month 7: 11
Sales for month 8: 1
Sales for month 9: 1
Sales for month 10: 1
Sales for month 11: 1
Sales for month 12: 1


Branch\Month:   1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12
Branch 1:       1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     11.0    1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0
1. Enter sales data.
2. Add a record for a new branch.
3. Delete record of an existing branch.
4. Calculate total sales.
5. Calculate percentage share of each branch.
6. Determine the month of peak sales.
7. Display sales of a specific month.
8. Display sales of a specific branch.
0. Done
2
Sales for the new branch number 2
Sales for month 1: 2
Sales for month 2: 3
Sales for month 3: 23
Sales for month 4: 2
Sales for month 5: 32
Sales for month 6: 2
Sales for month 7: 3
Sales for month 8: 3
Sales for month 9: 3
Sales for month 10: 3
Sales for month 11: 3
Sales for month 12: 3

Branch\Month:   1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12
Branch 1:       1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0     1.0     1.0
Branch 2:       2.0     3.0     23.0    2.0     32.0    2.0     3.0     3.0     3.0     3.0     3.0     3.0
```

as you see the months 7,8,9,10 in branch 1 were previously recorded but once I added Branch 2 they reappeared as zeros.

Here's the source code I wrote
Disclaimer " I know it's really messy "

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#define START_SIZE 2

int number_of_branches=0;
typedef struct
           {
              float sales[12];
              bool active;
           }Branch;

        Branch *Branchplace;
double function_one(void);
double function_two(void);
void function_three(void);
void function_four(void);



int main()
{
    int User_Selection;
    do
    {
    printf("1. Enter sales data.\n2. Add a record for a new branch.\n3. Delete record of an existing branch.\n4. Calculate total sales.\n5. Calculate percentage share of each branch.\n6. Determine the month of peak sales.\n7. Display sales of a specific month.\n8. Display sales of a specific branch.\n0. Done\n");
    scanf("%i",&User_Selection);

    switch (User_Selection)
    {
    case 0:
    {
        printf("Thankyou for your time :)\n");
        break;
    }

    case 1:
    {
        function_one();
        break;
    }

    case 2:
    {
      function_two();
        break;
    }
    case 3:
    {
        function_three();
        break;
    }
    case 4:
    {
         function_four();
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid input :)\n");
        break;
    }
    }
    }
    while(User_Selection!=0);
}


double function_one(void)
{
    //FILE *file = fopen("Sales.csv","a");
    printf("Ender number of branches: ");
    scanf("%d",&number_of_branches);
    //THIS IS FOR ALLOCATING MEMORY
    Branchplace = (Branch*) malloc(number_of_branches * sizeof(Branch));
    //Memory should be allocated by now...
    printf("\n");
        Branch Branches[number_of_branches];

        //printf("%d",number_of_branches);
        for(int b=0; b<number_of_branches; b++)
        {
            printf("Sales for branch %d: \n",(b+1));
            for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
            {
                printf("Sales for month %d: ",(x+1));
                scanf("%f",&(Branchplace+b)->sales[x]);
                //printf("\n%lf\n",Branches[b].sales[x]);
                //fprintf(file, "%d,%.2lf\n",x,Branches[b].sales[x]);
                //fprintf(file,"\n");
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }
     //fclose(file);
     printf("Branch\\Month:\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12\n");
     for(int b=0; b<number_of_branches; b++)
        {
            printf("Branch %d:\t",(b+1));
            for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
            {
                printf("%.1lf\t",(Branchplace+b)->sales[x]);

            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 0;


}

double function_two(void)
{
    //Reallocates enough memory for new branch
    number_of_branches++;
    Branchplace = realloc(Branchplace,(number_of_branches));
    //Enough memory should be allocated by now...
    printf("Sales for the new branch number %d\n",(number_of_branches));
    for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
{
                printf("Sales for month %d: ",(x+1));
                scanf("%f",&(Branchplace+number_of_branches-1)->sales[x]);
                //printf("\n%d\n",x);
}
     printf("\n");
     printf("Branch\\Month:\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9\t10\t11\t12\n");
     for(int b=0; b<number_of_branches; b++)
        {
            printf("Branch %d:\t",(b+1));
            for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
            {
                printf("%.1lf\t",(Branchplace+b)->sales[x]);

            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 1;

}

void function_three(void)
{
    Branch Branches[number_of_branches];
    int deleted_branch;
    printf("Which branch do you want to delete?\n");
    scanf("%d",&deleted_branch);
    Branches[deleted_branch].active=false;
    printf("Deleted branch %d\n",deleted_branch);
}

void function_four(void)
{
Branch Branches[number_of_branches];

    for(int n=0;n<number_of_branches;n++)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<12;x++)
        printf("%.f\n",Branches[n].sales[x]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend looking in your textbook and asking your instructor for help.

Comment: `realloc(Branchplace,(number_of_branches));`  So you are reallocating Branchplace to be 2 bytes in size?!  Shouldn't it be `realloc(Branchplace,number_of_branches * sizeof(Branch));`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah YES This actually solved the problem, Thank you so much sir!